# How to connect to MAMP remotely using AFNetworking?

Tags: php, objective-c, apache, afnetworking, lamp

I used to be able to connect to a local apache server via MAMP and the following AFNetworking configuration

```
#define kAPIHost @"http://192.168.0.70:8888"

#define kAPIPath @"iReporter/"
```

After setting up a LAMP server at `104.237.155.187` I am now trying to connect to it remotely. I've since updated the paths to read

```
#define kAPIHost @"http://104.123.155.187"

#define kAPIPath @"/var/www/html/example.com/public_html/iReporter/"
```

The response

```
error expected status code in (200-299) got 404
```

shows when attempting to register or log in.

Previously answered questions state `iphone AFNetworking Error: "Expected status code in (200 299), got 404"? ... 404 means that page or resource does not exist. Try also moving the slash to the baseUrl, i.e. baseURL to http://testurl.com/`.

The database can be connected to via PDO when browser testing, but how can I connect to the LAMP server via AFNetworking?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo '<p>Hello World!</p>';

// In the variables section below, replace user and password with your own MySQL credentials as created on your server
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root");
mysqli_select_db($link, "iReport");


// Check connection - if it fails, output will include the error message
if (!$conn) {
    die('<p>Connection failed: </p>' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo '<p>Connected successfully</p>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

***Update***

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf`

```
 <Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName mydomain.us
    ServerAlias www.domain.us
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

ErrorLog /var/www/html/example.com/logs/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/html/example.com/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

***Update***

`/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
104.237.123.187 newhost.mydomain.us newhost
2600:3c01::a123:b456:c789:d012 newhost.mydomain.us newhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: Your `kAPIPath` value `/var/www/html/example.com/public_html/iReporter/` looks like a local file system path, not a path in the URL. You should keep the `iReporter/` and if it doesn't work, check the Apache configuration.

Comment: Thank you @zrzka I agree the path felt odd to use in this format. I will post my Apache configuration file which I admittedly edited in a fog a few days back

Comment: I admittedly received some helpful tech support from my hosting provider in which the above AFNetworking paths were confirmed to be correct.

Comment: edited the question with Apache's `conf` and `host` files.

Comment: No, they're not correct. Read [`DocumentRoot`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) documentation. Your value is `/var/www/html`, your `kAPIPath` value is `/var/www/html/example.com/public_html/iReporter/` -> you have to strip `/var/www/html` part -> `example.com/public_html/iReporter/`.

Comment: Greatly appreciate your response. I am trying `#define kAPIHost @"http://104.237.155.187"
#define kAPIPath @"example.com/public_html/iReporter/"`

Comment: do you think the paths for the require statements should be edited as well? And if so how? `require("lib.php");
require("api.php");`

Comment: still getting the same response. update in progress...